# How to set Jack Audio Sink and Jack Audio Source as default sink and source

Tags: pulseaudio, jack

I use Ubuntu Studio 19.10, upgraded from 19.04, upgraded from 18.04.3.

Also, I use Jack Audio Connections Kit.

I want to know if there is an automatic way to set as default the Jack Audio Sink and Jack Audio Source.

I have to manually set this as on with PavuControl, each time I turn on my PC.

Is there a way to get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the *nik gnomic* idea, I could set it and it is very easy!

We have to go to the main *qjackctl* Setup menu, "Option" tab.

In that tab, we have two boxes: *Script to run after server starts* and *Script to run after starting*

Both boxes have to be filled with this line:

```
pacmd set-default-sink jack_out && pacmd set-default-source jack_in
```

That's all, folks!

Comment: There should be no need to run the commands to set defaults twice when starting QjackCtl

Comment: pacmd commands are synonymous with pactl commands but can use a live shell in terminal. pacmd commands can sometimes fail when used within a script so i favour the more reliable pactl commands where possible

Answer (score 1):

'pavucontrol' does not show default sink & source, only fallback devices

`pactl list sinks` will show for Pulseaudio JACK Sink - 'Name: jack_out'

`pactl list sources` will show for Pulseaudio JACK Source - 'Name: jack_in'

command to set these as default sink & source:

```
pactl set-default-sink jack_out; pactl set-default-source jack_in
```

to check default sink & source:

```
pactl get-default-sink; pactl get-default-source
```

Comment: Can you explain how your command work? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1191514/edit) your answer